# Bing web search api v5.0 returns "Resource not found" from Android app

Tags: android, bing, bing-api, android-ion, bing-search

I queried the Bing web search api with the "food" word.

This is the code:

```
    Ion.with(this)
            .load("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search")
            .setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setBodyParameter("q", "food")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    System.out.println("result = " + result);
                }
            });
```

I made this request with Ion library
[Android Ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion)

I got this response:

> {"statusCode":404,"message":"Resource not found"}

I followed Bing documentations carfully.

[Web Search API Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760781.aspx#simplerequest)

[Web Search API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760794.aspx)

I made a call via "Postman" client on Desktop Chrome browser and I got good fully response.

What is missing with the Android request?

## **Update**

I did the request with other AsyncHttp library called [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and it worked perfect!

I wonder what is wrong with Ion library..

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but The above code doesn't seem to append a '?' to the end of `...com/bing/v5.0/search` leaving you with `...com/bing/v5.0/searchq=food...` which would deifnitely throw a 404 error.

What you would want is `...com/bing/v5.0/search?q=food...`Perhaps the tool you used compensated for this.